# Label font size changing

Tags: vb.net, label

So I am making a small game in visual basics and at one of the thing I need to do is change the label size following an If statement. Sadly, It seemed way more complicated than I expected... I tried the following but it is "Read only"

```
If condition = false then
      lbltmp.Font.Size = 12pts
end if
```

I also Tried the following based on my friends advise:

```
With lbltmp.font
.size = 12
end with
```

I found similar question but they were all in c#, Which I don't know how to code in yet

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to change font instead of its size ;) See this: [LINQ Cookbook, Recipe 1: Change the font for all labels on a windows form (Kit George)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/vbteam/linq-cookbook-recipe-1-change-the-font-for-all-labels-on-a-windows-form-kit-george/)

```
label.Font = New Font("Comic Sans MS", 12, _
                    FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Underline)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to write this code. This will change the whole property of label.

```
Yourlabel.Font = New Font("Font Name", 10, FontStyle.Regular)
```

Answer (score -3):

You could actually change the size of it but you don't use code.
Instead just go to the properties of whatever you're trying to change the font size of, and go to the font property. Click on the 3 dots (...)  and a box will open. In that box, you can change the font and its size too. So you could change the size **there**!

(by the way this is the first time I've given an explanation on a website.)

Comment: If you read the question carefully, you will see that the question asks how to change the font "programmatically", not using a UI...