# How can I increase the font size of the user's input by one every 2 seconds in the code below?

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim mypicturebox As New PictureBox

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Label1.Text = "hello " & TextBox1.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
        Me.Label1.Text = "enter your name"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        mypicturebox.BackColor = Color.Red
        mypicturebox.Width = 50
        mypicturebox.Height = 50
        mypicturebox.Left = 100
        mypicturebox.Top = 100
        Me.Controls.Add(mypicturebox)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim MyFont As New Font(TextBox1.Font.FontFamily, 12, FontStyle.Bold)
        Dim size As Integer = 30
        Me.Font = New Font(Me.Font.FontFamily, size)
        Label1.Font = New Font(Label1.Font.FontFamily, size)
        Label1.Font.Size = Label1.Font.Size + 1
    End Sub
End Class
```

When I run the code, it says that the font size is read-only so I cannot change it.

Comment: `Label1.Font = New Font(Label1.Font.FontFamily, Label1.Font.Size + 1)`? You're already doing it the right way, but then immediately attempting to change the `Size` property. Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Label font size changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890446/label-font-size-changing)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Interval = 2000 '2 sec
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    TextBox1.Font = New Font(TextBox1.Font.FontFamily, TextBox1.Font.Size + 1)
End Sub
```